# How to enforce a relation between two variables

Tags: linear-programming, modeling, facility-location

I am having trouble formulating the following constraint:

I am looking to formulate a constraint that if a facility was opened at some point in time, then $Y[j,t]$ does always have to be $1$ from that point in time onwards (see values below). How do I do that?

| O[j,t] | Y[j,t] |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 1 |
| 0 | 1 |
| 0 | 1 |

Edit from comments:

It is also possible to close initially existing facilities using a closing variable $S[j,t]$. It is generally possible to close a facility, just not one that has been opened by the model using the $O[j,t]$ variable.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can activate variable $Y[j,t]$ when $O[j,t]$ is active ($O[j,t] \; \Longrightarrow \; Y[j,t]$) with:
$$
O[j,t] \le Y[j,t] \tag{1}
$$
And then make sure $Y[j,t]$ remains active ($Y[j,t] \; \Longrightarrow \; Y[j,t+1]$):
$$
Y[j,t] \le Y[j,t+1] \tag{2a}
$$

I suppose there is some cost on variables $Y[j,t]$ ? If so, this cost should preclude the solver from activating $Y[j,t]$ when $O[j,t]=Y[j,t-1]=0$.

Now, if you can close an exising facility, then $Y[j,t]$ should be active until the facility is closed, so you can adjust constraint $(2a)$ as follows:
$$
Y[j,t] \le Y[j,t+1] + S[j,t+1] \tag{2b}
$$
So if $Y[j,t]$ is active, in the following period you either maintain activity, or close the facility. And if you cannot reopen the facility, you need to impose:
$$
S[j,t] \le 1 - O[j,k] \quad \forall k=t,t+1,t+2,... \tag{3}
$$

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, it is much appreciated! :)

Comment: I also want to explore same. would you mind sharing resources or papers for dynamic facility location. Thanks.